# Android Text File Importing

Tags: java, android, encoding, character

I'm trying to import a text file to simply display in a textview using android.

The file is called "legal" and is located in res/raw

I use the following code to read in the file...

```
        BufferedReader bufferreader = new BufferedReader(new
        InputStreamReader(getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.legal), Charset.forName("UTF8")));
        String bufferLine;
        String tempText = "";
        try
        {
            while ((bufferLine = bufferreader.readLine()) != null)
            {
                tempText = tempText + bufferLine + "\n";
            }
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

When I try to display tempText in a TextView, directional "smart" quotes are displayed as as unknown characters. The text file, legal, is encoded with UTF8 (used notepad++). I can't seem to figure out what the problem is.

Comment: Not a solution to your problem (are you certain that the file was saved as UTF-8?) just an observation: that code will generate a lot of intermediate `String` objects that need to be garbage collected.  Using a `StringBuilder` would be more efficient, particularly if the file is large.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure "UTF8" is a valid charset name? [the documentation for Charset](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/nio/charset/Charset.html#forName%28java.lang.String%29) seems to suggest UTF-8

I usually just do

```
InputStreamReader(inputStream, "UTF-8")
```

and haven't had any problems. I have had problems with utf encoded html style. As in `&#UNICODENUMBER;`

This fixed those problems

```
txtView.setText(Html.fromHtml(str).toString());
```

**EDIT**

Since the above didn't help you I would try the following:

```
txtView.setText(Html.fromHtml("&#8220;" + " Hello World " + "&#8221;").toString());
```

Just to see if the font used has support for the characters (I'm guessing you are after curling quotes). If it does render, there must be a issue with either the way you read the file (even-though, it looks valid enough), or the actual file.

Hope that helps :)

Comment: Thanks for your response. Tried changing the string to "UTF-8" and it doesn't change anything. I also tried the utf html method you described, and that didn't help either.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I think something was wrong with the file I was encoding originally, because the device itself has no problems displaying special characters if things are done properly. Thanks!